# javadoc @link

Tags: javadoc

I wrote two methods in class Util:

```
public static final <T> T[] copy1(T[] source) {...}
public static final <T> T[] copy2(T[] source) {...}
```

Javadoc for method copy2 includes:

```
{@link #copy1(Object[]) copy}
```

and as a test includes also:

```
{@link Integer#highestOneBit(int) highestOneBit}
```

When I click the highestOneBit link it works.
When I click the copy link, it doesnt work correctly, it links to the Util class?!
Java version 1.5.0_16.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What happens when you link to `copy(T[])` instead of `copy(Object[])`? On my machine, that works.

Comment: That's it.
The reason I used Object[], is because that was the code generated, when after the # sign, you try code completion (Ctrl-Space) in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The link to #copy1 is creating a link to the internal anchor for your method copy1(). Where else did you expect it to go?

Comment: To be more specific: it links to the class definition.
I was expecting that it would link to the method in the class.